# Entity Framework / SQL - nullable column "could not be set to a 'null' value"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nullable, ef-database-first

Logging caught an error in our application which I have been unable to reproduce. It did, however, catch the message which was:

> The 'MyProperty' property on 'MyTable' could not be set to a 'null' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.Int32'.

Which is fine, except that the 'MyProperty' property is certainly nullable. It's set to nullable in the table.

```
[MyProperty] [int] NULL,
```

And in the EDMX file for Entity Framework, Nullable was set to (None) but the Entity itself shows the property as nullable:

```
public Nullable<int> MyProperty { get; set; }
```

Intellisense shows this as `int?` when creating Entities of this class.

Why is the system complaining about setting this field to null?

Comment: May be in your model it is null-able but what it is in your database. Or Do you have Fluent API configuration for this entity?

Comment: @TanvirArjel As the question states, I've checked the database and it's set to Null

Comment: What about Fluent API?

Comment: @TanvirArjel We're not using fluent

Comment: Then its really misterious !

Answer (score 0):

Even though the Entity generate had `Nullable<int>` for the property, setting it to `Nullable = true` in the EDMX seems to have fixed the problem.